# Imported PLY file appears blank

Tags: import

I have imported a PLY file sent to me into a new Blender file. There is a Vert count and all the rest displayed at the top of the window, but I don't see anything. Do I need to adjust display options or something?

Comment: maybe is in a defferent scale, either too big or too small. Select the object on the outliner and Press Numpad period

Comment: @cegaton Right! changed the View > Clip settings to stop it from disappearing when i zoom, moved its origin to its surface, and moved it to the cursor at the origin. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think most .PLY object come very big. 
The object is here but you need to scale it down a lot and center it.
This is my process with this sample file :
http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/ply/airplane.ply

1. file import .ply
2. CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-C to set the Origin to Geometry or in the menu 
   [image]
3. ALT-G to make sure your object is in the center
4. **scale S to something like 0.02**
5. I would suggest to immediately Apply Scale (CTRL-A) to ensure correct scaling.